# Find all documents where field exists literally: either it has a value or it is null in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, exists

I know how to determine the documents in `Elasticsearch` `6.8` with the non empty field, e.g.:

```
GET grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "exists": {
          "field": "hgmd_accession"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

But how to return existing (non null) together with empty values in one query? I need to find the documents where the value literally exists: either empty or set to null. There can be some documents in my index where the field is just not there at all and I need to `_reindex` the ones that just have the field present in any form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think null values can be searched because they are not indexed by elasticsearch.

If you can change your index mapping then you should look into the null_value property provided by elasticsearch.
Find it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/null-value.html